# When developing 3D Map, which way is better in this constraint?

Tags: mobile, 3d

I'm tring to develop 3D Map, and I found 3 solutions.

1. Use game engine(like unity) or
2. Use 3D graphic API(opengl, etc) or
3. Web app

Is there another way to do?
And which one(those three solutions) is better?(with reason)

Constraints
development period - 1 year, 3 programmers, can be run on mobile.

THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those solutions allows you to draw some 3D content so if you don't have more specific needs you can look at other details:

**Game Engine (e.g.UNITY)** :

+Easy to start with

+Many components already done (like terrain, sky, water, GUI)

+Multiplatform - UNITY supports iOS, Android, PC, web out of the box.

-It's often hard to modify the working components for you own needs.

-Everything should be done in an engine-specific way.

**3D API** :

+Most universal - what you learn here is general 3D knowledge, useful in different engines/APIs.

+Full controll - you do everything by hand

-You need much of work for a decent project

-Platform specific

**Web app** :

+*DEPLOY!!!* - no installation, web storage and client/server architecture out of the box, access through the web, simple updates for all users.

-Will (probably) not work on mobile browsers.

-You don't have some cutting-edge features.

---

If you really need mobile, then I'd go for UNITY, the rest depends on your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks! It was so helpful. Sorry, I'm late.